# How to View the Windows form application In Windows Service Application running as service

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, windows-services, installation

I have a Windows Service Application which contains one Service.cs and one Windows Form Application.Now as per my requirement i have to make a setup installer of this application which i did using Visual Studio Setup project under Deployment Section.

Now if i will install my setup Windows Service file will be added as Service and we can see it and its working fine also but i am not seeing the windows form application.

In the control panel add/remove program my application has been added as i am seeing it but windows form application is not showing in All programs of start button.

Please help me .
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It doesn't show up in all programs unless you've specified that a shortcut should be added to the programs menu - have you specified that in your setup project?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Thank you very much sir ..Will you please tell me how to specify it as i very new in this ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If this is urgent:**

In the File System Editor for the setup project, it should show the target machine's file system. By default, the primary outputs you've specified will be set to install to the "Application Folder". But what you want to do is to look under the "User's Programs Menu" (I can't remember if this shows up by default - if not, right click "File System on Target Machine", "Add Special Folder" and select this folder).

Then, in the right-hand pane, right click and choose "Create New Shortcut", navigate down through "Application Folder", select the windows forms application and hit OK. Then give it a suitable name.

**If this isn't urgent** - go and find a better setup tool and learn how to do similar things to the above using that tool. Visual Studio 2010 was the *last* version to include the Setup project support, so spending time learning this tool now is wasted time. Better to find a tool that will continue to work as you upgrade VS versions. I'd normally suggest [WiX](http://wixtoolset.org/) since it comes at a great price (free) but it does have a learning curve (since you author the setup in XML).

Comment: Sir which folder i need to select from "Add Special Folder" as so many folders are there?

Comment: @Adi - "User's Programs Menu" - as I said, I can't remember if it's shown by default. You only need to do the "Add Special Folder" bit if that folder isn't already shown.

Comment: I under Stood Sir..Thank you very much.One more thing i need to clarify as how to Select windows form application as this is included under the windows Service application project and upon navigating "Application folder" i am getting full application folder